# Setting CSS classes with current_user

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble arriving at an approach to this problem. tl;dr I want to be able to set the css class of an li to the name of the current_user that posted the chat. Then based on that class, I'll apply different styling.

This is for a chat window and I want all the current users messages to display on one side and I want all other messages to display on the other side with a different color, etc.

I have a `file.js.coffee` that basically reads in some user input and apends it to an ordered list and adds some elements and classes along the way

```
      projectRef.on "child_added", (snapshot) ->
        message = snapshot.val()
        $("<li class='self'>").append($("<div class='message'>").append($("<p>").text(message.text))).prepend($("<b/>").text(message.name + ": ")).appendTo $("#messagesDiv")
        $("#messagesDiv")[0].scrollTop = $("#messagesDiv")[0].scrollHeight

      $("#messageInput").keypress (e) ->
        if e.keyCode is 13
          text = $("#messageInput").val()
          projectRef.push 
            name: userName
            text: text
          $("#messageInput").val ""
```

The above would yield something like this in the browser

```
<li class="self">
 <b>User : </b>
  <div class="message">
   <p>My chatt message from file.js.coffee!!</p>
  </div>
</li>
```

That 'self' class in the li is what I have been trying to dynamically set based on the current_user. So I have 2 issues - 1. I'm trying to figure out who posted the li and 2. I'm trying to dynamically set the class of that li based on the user that chatted/posted it.

My thinking was something along the lines of in the file.js.coffee use JQuery to grab that li and add the `<%= current_user.name %>` as a class then I could have a file.js.erb where I would do something like

```
<% unless $('li').hasClass('<%= current_user.name %>'); %>
    <%= $('li').toggleClass('others') %>
<% end %>
```

This way it checks if the class of the target `li` is from the current user and if it is keep the css class as self if not toggle it to others. Then I could style the classes appropriately (left, right, `background-color:blue;`, etc).

Is there a more correct way to approach this problem given what I am trying to accomplish? I think so..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are saying you're trying to assign a class as the current user's name.

I'm wondering if going that far is necessary.

Assigning the list element with a class named "current_user" might be enough, then have separate CSS to control anything with class named "current_user".

Here's an [example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shanosha/m8szn/).

CSS

```
li {
    list-style:none;
    clear:both;

    float:right;
    text-align:right;
    background-color:#A7A2A0;
    border:1px solid #EEE;
    width:200px;
    margin:10px;
    padding:5px;
}
li.current_user {
    float:left;
    text-align:left;
    background-color:#24887F;
}
```

HTML

```
<li class="current_user">
    <b>Current User:</b>
    <div class="message">
    <p>My message!</p>
    </div>
</li>
<li>
    <b>All Other Users:</b>
    <div class="message">
    <p>Other person's smessage.</p>
    </div>
</li>
```

**UPDATE:**
Looking at the firebase example I altered it to add a class "current_user" if the username matched the the name of the user that wrote the message. Below is the part of the code that I altered in the "displayChatMessage" function, I also added CSS to the head section for the "current_user" class.

Here's a [link to the working example](https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/play.html#-IzR1yE-r6Pm0xLRWUGn), view it in to different web browsers using different usernames at the same time to see.

```
function displayChatMessage(name, text) {
  if(name == $('#nameInput').val()){
    $('<div/>').text(text).prepend($('<em/>').text(name+': ')).appendTo($('#messagesDiv')).addClass('current_user');
    $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollTop = $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollHeight;
  }
  else{
    $('<div/>').text(text).prepend($('<em/>').text(name+': ')).appendTo($('#messagesDiv'));
    $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollTop = $('#messagesDiv')[0].scrollHeight;
  }
};
```

This is the CSS I added to the head.

```
<style type="text/css">
  .current_user {
    background-color:#24887F;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: Maybe I'm completely missing something, but I am struggling with how to identify that a chat posted will have been from the current_user. I dont think @BillyChan's answer will work because I am writing to [firebase](http://firebase.com) servers and not a message model I have created. Still confused :/

Comment: @Tmacram I looked at the firebase example and altered it to add a class of "current_user" as it writes the message to the chat window if the current user's name matches the name of the person that wrote the message.

Use this example in two different web browsers at the same time using different usernames.

[link](https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/play.html#-IzR1yE-r6Pm0xLRWUGn)

Comment: @Tmacram I checked out firebases example and altered it to do what we are discussing. Please see the update I added to my answer above. I've posted snippets of the code and a link to the working example.

Answer (score 0):

There are many users using the app concurrently. But for every user, there is only one current_user in session. Don't mix it up.

Since the message is to be processed by server, you can easily add a new attribute of `message.klass` in server side by judging the message comes from current_user. If it is, the class may be `current`, else blank or `others`.

Then, in JS

```
$('li').addClass('<%= message.klass %>')
```